# Where can I download Windows 10 S?

Tags: windows-10, iso-image

I need to download Windows 10 S to test my app. Any idea where can I get its ISO?

Comment: Microsoft hasn't published one.  There are no Windows 10 S devices that have actually been released, in other words, nobody's actual has a Windows 10 S device

Comment: So even if we wanted to create one from a device we wouldn't be able to, because, there isn't a single Windows 10 S device on the market as of today.

Comment: I've added new details to my answer. Check it.

Comment: See this:: http://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/download-windows-10-s-iso-file/

Comment: @Biswa: Can't open it -- says "whitelist this site" and displays an annoying overlay.

Comment: Disable any adblocker to open that site.

Comment: @Biswa: not worth it.

Comment: have you tried the steps that MS listed to enforce the restrictions to simulate the S edition? can you install your desktop app via store? does it run?

Comment: Microsoft now provides the Win10 S ISO via MSDN subscription. So get it there

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/1321737/how-to-enable-windows-10-s-mode-for-version-1803
you can try windows 10 in S mode.

Answer (score 2):

This [version is only available to OEMs](https://translate.google.com/translate?sl=de&tl=en&js=y&prev=_t&hl=de&ie=UTF-8&u=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.drwindows.de%2Fcontent%2F12595-windows-10-s-antworten-viele-detailfragen.html&edit-text=) and Volume license education customers according to this German website where the author asked Microsoft.

> **Can I buy Windows 10 S?**
>   Some users have already asked if they can buy Windows 10 S individually, because they see in it the optimal
>   solution, eg for family members. 
>   **Currently, it is not planned to distribute Windows 10 S separately, it
>   is only made available to the OEMs. The only exception is that Windows
>   10 S is available as an option through the volume licensing program
>   for educational facilities**, which means that existing devices can be
>   upgraded.

Windows 10 S only allows install of Apps from Store. So if you are desktop developer, [bring your application to store](https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2016/09/14/apps-built-using-the-desktop-bridge-now-available-in-the-windows-store/) to be able to use in on Windows 10 S.

In 1703, there is already an option to only allow app setup via store (`Allow apps from Store only`).

[image]

Activate this option to emulate `Windows 10 S`.

The `15063.0.170317-1834.RS2_RELEASE_CLIENTCLOUD_OEM_X64FRE_EN-US.ISO` leaked to the Internet some time ago, so try to get it. But setup can be complicated because it also doesn't allow you to install drivers.

Microsoft provides [some guides](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/appconsult/2017/06/15/porting-and-testing-your-classic-desktop-applications-on-windows-10-s-with-the-desktop-bridge/) how to [simulate Windows 10 S for development purpose to test your applications](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/porting/desktop-to-uwp-test-windows-s).

Comment: Yes, my app is a Centennial app. What I don't understand is how do they expect developers to have a working software for their store if there's no way to download that OS to test it?

Comment: @c00000fd It’s still Windows 10. Any Windows 10 PC will do for testing your Windows Store app. Because you wouldn’t even be able to install device drivers, installing Windows 10 S is not feasible even for developers.

Comment: ok, if your app is a Centennial app, install a fresh 1703 and set the option to only allow store apps: https://www.windowscentral.com/sites/wpcentral.com/files/styles/xlarge/public/field/image/2017/03/installing-apps-1703.jpg and now try to install the app from store and look if it works fine. But I think the final of the Win10 S will leak.

Comment: you don't need to wait for Windows 10 S to publish Windows Store app. Any Windows 10 can run those apps. Even some windows 8/8.1 can