# How to enable Windows 10 S mode for version 1803?

Tags: windows-10

Following the attached link, i tried to enable S mode from my win10 Pro. But it was not successful. I did each step exactly and there wasn't any errors appeared. But my HDD had been formated when i tried it. I wanna cry. :(( Please help me to setup it. Thanks

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/windows-10-s-deployment-sxs

Comment: You followed instructions that are intended for system administrators to deploy Windows 10 S to machines.  You do understand, once you enable Windows S mode, it cannot be reversed?  Are you sure you really want to do this?

Comment: I read some additional instructions, and it seems, the switch is only one-way.  Which means if you don't already have it enabled, you would have to reinstall Windows 10 with it enabled already, in order to accomplish your goals.

Comment: create a [new ISO with S Mode enabled](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/windows-10-s-enable-s-mode) and install it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have resolved this problem.
Following the link i had posted. There are some steps you must do to re-install windows 10 in S mode:
-from start to "Enable customizations". Note: use ":" instead of "=" at the command: "DISM /Image=C:\mount\windows /Apply-Unattend=C:\mount\windows\Windows\Panther\unattend.xml".
- Unmount WinRE Image and make a copy
- Copy install.wim and winre.wim to your USB drive. Note: at the step copy scripts folder to T:\, you must copy the contents in folder scripts\old to scripts.
- Deploy the image to reference PC.
Note: it will clean your hard disk. be careful. all partition will be cleared. dont try it on your main PC. Thank for your help and goodluck!!!

Answer (score 4):

You cannot enable S mode, you can only disable it.

See the Microsoft article
[Windows 10 in S mode FAQ](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4020089/windows-10-in-s-mode-faq).
Below are some excerpts from the article.

> **How does Windows 10 S change with the release of the April 2018 Update for Windows 10?**
>
> With the release of Windows 10, the April 2018 Update, “Windows 10 S”
> becomes a mode of Windows 10 (called “S mode”) that is available in
> more editions of Windows (not just Windows 10 Pro).
>
> You’ll be able to buy new PCs with either Windows 10 Home in S mode or
> Windows 10 Pro in S mode preinstalled.
>
> If you have an existing Windows 10 S device, when you install the
> April 2018 Update, the device will become a Windows 10 Pro in S mode
> device.
>
> **Can i switch out of S mode on my Windows 10 PC?**
>
> You can switch out of S mode easily at any time through the Microsoft
> Store within Windows. There is no charge for switching the mode. The
> switch is one-way; if you make the switch, you won't be able to go
> back to S mode. See below for important additional limitations when
> switching out of S mode on devices that use the Qualcomm Snapdragon
> processor.
>
> To learn more or switch out of S mode, go to the Microsoft Store
> within Windows and search for “switch out of S mode”.
>
> **Note**
>
> **Switching out of S mode is one-way. If you make the switch, you won't
> be able to go back to Windows 10 in S mode.**